# SQL Find entries WHERE a specific day is on or between dateTimeStart and dateTimeFinish

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, phpmyadmin

I'm looking to run a query that gets all rows that occur on a specific date.

[image]

For example, the query should return both of these entries, if I want all entries that occured on 2019-03-21.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @AbraCadaver both only work for the first entry, not the second one.

Comment: `WHERE '2019-03-21' BETWEEN DATE(StartDateTime) AND DATE(EndDateTime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to check for an overlap, of datetime values from the rows, with start and end datetime

visually, given a start and end we want to check overlap for, there are several possibilities:

```
     start       end
       |          | 
  s--e |          |             no overlap
  s----e          |             overlap (*)
  s--------e      |             overlap
  s---------------e             overlap
  s------------------e          overlap
       s---e      |             overlap
       s----------e             overlap
       s-------------e          overlap
       |  s---e   |             overlap
       |  s-------e             overlap
       |  s----------e          overlap
       |          s----e        overlap (*)
       |          |  s---e      no overlap
```

to find rows that do not overlap (assuming that start_date_time is always before end_date_time, and both are non-null) we could use a test like this:

```
  WHERE r.end_date_time    <  '2019-03-21 00:00'
     OR r.start_date_time  >= '2019-03-22 00:00'
```

If the "end" on the row is *before* the start of the range we want to test, there is no overlap.  Or, if the "start" on the row is *on or after* the end of the range, there is no overlap.

This is checking for any overlap at any time on 3/21/2019. ("start" is 3/21, and "end" is 3/22.)

Inverting that condition would give us rows that *do* overlap:

```
  WHERE NOT ( r.end_date_time    <  '2019-03-21 00:00'
           OR r.start_date_time  >= '2019-03-22 00:00'
            )
```

Which can be rewritten:

```
  WHERE  r.end_date_time    >= '2019-03-21 00:00'
    AND  r.start_date_time  <  '2019-03-22 00:00'
```

(Note that we need a more elaborate condition, if the values of start_date_time and/or end_date_time can be NULL, or if end_date_time can be before start_date_time.)

Comment: Once we get our head wrapped around how to check for an overlap, the syntax for the condition just naturally falls out.  Just details dealing with those boundary conditions, if the only overlap is right at the exact second of the start/end of the range. I typically do ranges with this pattern : `dt >= start AND dt < end`,  checking "less than" the end of the range (e.g. using midnight of the following day, the first second that is not in the range.)

Comment: This same pattern works for checking overlap of any ranges, not just a "day". Other solutions that make use of `DATE()` function (to lop off times of datetime values)  can work in the special case checking for overlap on just one day with midnight boundaries. e.g. what if we need to check for overlap with range from 3/21 8AM and 3/21 3PM,  or 3/25 5AM,  ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have a `DATE` (no time) and you need to check with a `DATETIME`, then ignore the time.  Extract the `DATE` portion of the `DATETIME` column and check if your date is between those dates:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
         WHERE '2019-03-21' BETWEEN DATE(StartDateTime) AND DATE(EndDateTime)
```

Doing the opposite may also work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
         WHERE CAST('2019-03-21' AS DATETIME) BETWEEN StartDateTime AND EndDateTime
```

Comment: Wrapping a column in a function will prevent MySQL from making effective use of an index; we typically prefer to use bare columns in predicates. It doesn't make a difference on trivial sets, but performance impact can be significant on non-trivial sets.

Answer (score -1):

You want:

```
where '2019-03-21' <= date(enddatetime) and
      '2019-03-21' >= date(startDatetime)
```

However, the most efficient way to write the query would be:

```
where enddatetime >= date('2019-03-21') and
      startdatetime < date('2019-03-21') + interval '1 day'
```

Comment: do you need to wrap `DATE()` around the cols as he has date-times, or does mysql work that our?

Comment: this seems reasonable to me, not sure why this answer is downvoted. +10

Answer (score -2):

**You can use the date function:**

```
SELECT * from table where date(my_date) = '2019-03-21'
```

Source: [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)